How can this expression be interpreted
How may the following expression be interpreted? $I=\oint_{C} f(z)|dz|$..
My approach is to simplify $I$ as $I=\oint_{C}f(z)\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$ but it seems inconclusive.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am asking that if the above expression is meaningful then what does it means.

If $\gamma:I\to C$ is a $C^1$ parametrisation of the curve we put $\oint_C f(z)|dz|:=\int_I f(\gamma(t))\cdot|\gamma'(t)|dt$. What changes from the usual definition of contour integration $\int_C f(z)dz$ is the presence of $|\gamma'|$ rather than $\gamma'$. $|\cdot|$ is of course complex modulus.
You can think of $|\gamma'(t)|dt$ as the infinitesimal increase in length of the curve, justifying "$|dz|$" (the size of the change in $z$). Indeed $\ell(C)=\int_I|\gamma'(t)|dt$ can be proven; if $\ell(t)$ is the arclength of the curve up to time $t$, then it can be shown (e.g. in Ted Shifrin's differential geometry notes) that the derivative $\ell'(t)$ is equal to $|\gamma'(t)|$.
